# Pattern Matching failed when "\" is input

Tags: java, regex, escaping

My pattern is something like this:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-\\.]{1,}@{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-.]{1,}$"
```

But when I try to match something with a backslash in it, like this:

```
"abc\\@abc"
```

...it does not match.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: Sorry for Not mentioning it earlier. Its Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping each backslash of your test string with an additional backslash: e.g.

`"abc\\\\@abc"` becomes `"abc\\\\\\\\@abc"`

Comment: I believe the second string in the question is an example of what he's trying to match, not as a regex.  That's why I restored the quotes that were removed by an earlier editor, to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

try with below pattern

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-\\\\.]{1,}@{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-.]{1,}$";
```

or

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-\\{0,}}.]{1,}@{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-.]{1,}$";
```

The expression \\ matches a single backslash \

Comment: When i use the 1st option of Yours, the "@" is accepted multiple times in input whereas according to the pattern it should accept only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"\\\\"` if you want the end result to look like `"\"`

why, you ask?
The Java compiler sees the string `"\\\\"` and turns that into `"\\"`  as `"\"` is an escape character.

Afterwards the regular expression sees the string `"\\"` and turns it into `"\"` as an `"\"` is an escape character.

so to want a single backslash you must put in four.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're writing the regex in your Java source code, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "^[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-\\.]{1,}@{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&amp;/+-.]{1,}$"
);
```

I'm also assuming you meant `\\.` as a backslash followed by a dot, not as an escaped dot.

Because it's in a string literal, you have to escape backslashes one more time.  That means you have to use four backslashes in the regex to match one in the target string.  You also need to escape the `-` (hyphen) so the regex compiler doesn't think (for example) that `[+-.]` is meant to be a range expression like `[0-9]` or `[a-z]`.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&/+\\\\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_'^&/+.-]+$"
```

I also changed your `{1,}` to `+` because it means the same thing, and got rid of the `{1,1}` because it doesn't do anything.  And I changed your `&amp;` to `&`.  I don't know how that got in there, but if you wrote it that way in your source code, it's wrong.